# Remove Activities from Stack

Tags: android, android-activity, stack, lifecycle

In `Main`, there are buttons to start `A` and `X`

```
          /--> A --> B
         / 
    Main
         \
          \--> X
```

There is a button in `B` to take it from `B --> X`.  If that happens, `A` and `B` should be removed from the activity stack, so that pressing `back` in `X` returns to `Main`

Comment: Ok. If you go back from B what activity you want to display either A or Main ??

Comment: back from B should return to A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on `Activity X`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
Intent i = new Intent(X.this, Main.class);
i.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(i); 
}
```

It Will Clear the Activity Stack and launches the Main Activity. So if you press back from `Activity B` it goes to `Activity A`. Back in `Activity X` will launch your `Main Activity` with no history in your stack.

Comment: @codeMagic yes what happens if he press back from activity X. He will end up in activity B. Am i right?

Comment: I upvoted but that was before I saw the other answer by user2668298. That one might be better ;)